# 1/2" IPS -> Aerator?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a kitchen faucet that currently has a faulty dual mode (shower/aerator) nozzle. The nozzle has a 1/2" MIP thread.

I would like the replace the nozzle with a standard aerator, but my local hardware store tells me that such a thing doesn't exist (i.e. 1/2" MIP aerator).

Is this so? Any way to adapt a normal aerator to the thread I have?

Thanks!

Comment: The link was just a sample of a quick search, I saw items in amazon and other plumbing websites, and even on pinterest. So like the keebler elves, they do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th MIP thread is PART of the faucet and not a separate unit you can remove?
https://www.plumbingsupply.com/aerator.html

MIP/FTP/NPT..... They make converters, and also Aerators with 1/2 IP threads.

Comment: Thanks for that. Believe it or not, the part you found (by BrassCraft) seems to be alone in being able to convert between IPS and faucet thread. I had to get another male-to-male nipple as well, but it did the trick. :)